# Use of [] in fscanf()

Tags: c, input, scanf

I've a text file with following contents:

```
"abc","def","ghi"
```

The following works to read the file contents properly:

```
int main()
{
    char name[1024] = {0};
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while(1)
    {
        if (fscanf(file, " %[\",]s ", name) == EOF)
            break;
        if (fscanf(file, " %[a-zA-Z]s ", name) == EOF)
            break;

        printf("%s\n", name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the following fails:

```
int main()
{
    char name[1024] = {0}, garbage[5];
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while(1)
    {
        if (fscanf(file, " %[\",]s%[a-zA-Z]s ", garbage, name) == EOF)
            break;

        printf("%s\n", name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MSVC++ 08. What am I missing? I'm looking for a solution with single `fscanf()` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Whilst there are plenty of suggestions that fix your issue, the best solution is not to use `fscanf` for this sort of thing.  You will end up with a much more robust solution (i.e. dealing with weird edge-cases and malformed input) if you write your own lexer state-machine.

Comment: @Oli: i agree. i was solving a programming problem where i didn't have to deal with weird input. for all-valid input cases, i'd love to do it by the machine, rather than manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works??? Pure bad luck :-)

Your conversion specifications mean

```
" %[\",]s "
         ^= optionally skip whitespace
        ^== read a literal 's'
  ^^^^^^=== read an unlimited string of quotes and commas
 ^========= optionally skip whitespace
```

and

```
" %[a-zA-Z]s "
            ^= optionally skip whitespace
           ^== read a literal 's'
  ^^^^^^^^^=== read an unlimited string of letters
 ^============ optionally skip whitespace
```

and

```
" %[\",]s%[a-zA-Z]s "
                   ^= optionally skip whitespace
                  ^== read a literal 's'
         ^^^^^^^^^=== read an unlimited string of letters
        ^============ read a literal 's'
  ^^^^^^============= read an unlimited string of quotes and commas
 ^=================== optionally skip whitespace
```

I think you want

```
" %4[\",]%1023[a-zA-Z] "
                      ^= optionally skip whitespace
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^== read a string of at most 1023 letters
  ^^^^^^^=============== read a string of at most 4 quotes and commas
 ^====================== optionally skip whitespace
```

---

Other than that, `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions or EOF on error. You're comparing the result value with EOF when you should be comparing to 1 (or 2, or whatever): compare to the number of conversions you expect.

```
if (scanf() == 3) /* expected 3 conversions */
{ /* ok */ }
else { /* oops, something went wrong */ }
```

Comment: i thought the 's' is of 'string'. :( i actually totally forgot how [] works. couldn't find it using google. and for pure bad luck ;) it worked out!

Answer (score 4):

1. Brackets are their own conversion specifier, not a modifier. `%[a-zA-Z]s` means "match any number of alphabetic characters and assign to `name`, then match a literal `s`. Remove the `s` characters.
2. If you want to match something but discard it, use asterisk and not a garbage buffer: `%*[\",]`.
3. *scanf* won't return `EOF` if at least one specifier matched before the file ended. This means you'll get an erroneous loop when the file pointer is after the `i`. Consider testing the count of specifiers assigned, or another `"%*[\"]"` at the end to slurp up the trailing quotes.

This is also why the first version worked. The literal `s` failed to match, but the first conversion succeeded, so you got `name` but not `EOF`.

---

```
if (fscanf(file, " %*[\",]%[a-zA-Z] ", name) < 1)
    break;
```

or

```
fscanf(file, " %*[\",]%[a-zA-Z]%*[\"] ", name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "s" conversion flag, as in:

```
if (fscanf(file, " %[\",]%[a-zA-Z] ", garbage, name) < 2)
```

Note that I must compare to 2 rather than EOF since the last quotation mark will get read-in on the next iteration.

**EDIT**: I'm surprised your first code sample works too, but it ran just fine with gcc on Mac OS X, so this isn't a Microsoft-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

the following should work:

```
      if (fscanf(file, " %[\",]%[a-zA-Z] ", garbage, name) == EOF) 
        break;
```